# Unknown command: `C error displayed when using SED to delete a line in shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, sed

I am running the below command in a while loop. If my line matches my scenario it will delete that line. I have 2 example 1st one working 2nd one fails.
Can someone point out my mistake?

Example 1 :

```
line="!QCfg { Id: "ABC_XTQK", que: "QUE_166072_XTQK_ROS_CRIBE_PONSE_000", tryPro: false },"
sed -i "/$line/"'d' <FILENAME>
```

Example 2 :

```
line="ABC_XYZ: !PCfg { des: "AB/CDEF/GHI/XYZ/001", type: TOMATO, delMod: DIRECT },"
sed -i "/$line/"'d' <FILENAME>
```

Comment: I got the answer with a hit and try i had to change delimiter as "/" was creating the issue .

So I use "|" as a delimiter so the correct command would be  sed -i "\|$line|d" <FileName>

Comment: You can either delete your question or you can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer with a hit and try i had to change delimiter as "/" was creating the issue . So I use "|" as a delimiter so the correct command would be :

```
sed -i "\|$line|d" <FileName>
```